# Combinations of winning scholarships

Tags: combinatorics

If six students are eligible for two scholarships worth 1k each, how many different combinations of 2 students winning the 2 scholarships are possible?

My attempt 6 nCr 2.

How am I wrong?

Comment: Are the scholarships distinguishable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the scholarships are **identical**, and a student **cannot** win both, then your answer of $\binom{6}{2}=15$ is perfectly correct.

If a student is allowed to win both, we have to add $6$ to this.

If the scholarships are **named** (highest standing in Math, highest standing in Physics) then the Math scholarship can be awarded in $6$ ways, and for each way so can the Physics scholarship, for a total of $6^2$.

**Remark:** It unfortunately happens fairly often in elementary combinatorics/probability  that a "word problem" can be interpreted in several inequivalent ways. Your interpretation (two different students are chosen, the scholarships are identical) is I think the most reasonable one, but it is not the only one.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure you don't double count.

Call each student A, B, C, etc. Student A winning scholarship 1 and B winning scholarship 2 is the same event as A winning scholarship 2 and B winning scholarship 1.

Comment: $\binom{6}{2}$ (which is what the author did) wouldn't double count.

Comment: @AndreNicolas this book's answer is 36. Is the book incorrect?

Comment: @Ben: I have discussed possible interpretations of the question in my answer. One of the interpretations yields the answer $36$. Where the book is "incorrect" is in giving a question that can be interpreted in several ways.

Answer (score 0):

The "choose" function $\frac{n!}{k!(n - k)!}$ ignores order. So if both of your scholarships are the same, 6 choose 2 is correct. That's the situation where Abe winning scholarship 1 and Betty winning scholarship 2 is the same as Betty winning scholarship 1 and Abe winning scholarship 2.

If that's *not* what you're trying to count, if you *do* care about order, then the "permute" function $\frac{n!}{k!}$ is what you want.